# props.names.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, list, forms, controlled-component

I have a react component called App that contains 2 components: Form and Table. And both of them are controlled component.
In the form, there is an input element and a button.
The input element has an onChange attribute; whenever the value changes it changes the value in the App's state.
The button has an onClick attribute that is provided by the App component; Whenever the button is clicked, the state's firstNames (which is an array) will be added with the state value of firstname.

The problem is when I clicked the button, it will throw an error saying that I didn't pass in an array and that it doesn't have a map method, even though in the call back, the updated state does show an array. 
Below is the code:

```
function Form(props) {
  return (
    <form>
      <label>
        Item: <input value={props.value} onChange={props.handleChange} />
      </label>
      <button onClick={props.handleClick}>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

function Table(props) {
  let firstNames = props.names.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{item}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>{firstNames}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputField: "",
      firstNames: ["Joey", "Chloe"],
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ inputField: event.target.value });
  }
  handleClick() {
    this.setState(
      {
        firstNames: this.state.firstNames.push(this.state.inputField),
      },
      console.log(this.state.firstNames)
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form
          value={this.state.inputField}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          handleClick={this.handleClick}
        />
        <Table names={this.state.firstNames} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) mutates the original array, but it returns the `length` of the updated array, therefor, after the initial push, your `firstNames` inside state will be a number, which doesn't have `map`

You shouldn't mutate state variables, you should create a new array instead when adding a new name, for example, like this:

```
this.setState({
    firstNames: [...this.state.firstNames, this.state.inputField]
})
```

The full sample code would then look something like this:

```js
function Form(props) {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={props.handleClick}>
      <label>
        Item: <input value={props.value} onChange={props.handleChange} />
      </label>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

function Table(props) {
  let firstNames = props.names.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{item}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>{firstNames}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputField: "",
      firstNames: ["Joey", "Chloe"],
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ inputField: event.target.value });
  }
  handleClick( e ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState(
      {
        firstNames: [...this.state.firstNames, this.state.inputField],
        inputField: ''
      }, () => console.log(this.state.firstNames) );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form
          value={this.state.inputField}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          handleClick={this.handleClick}
        />
        <Table names={this.state.firstNames} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Following 2 things I still updated in your code:

Added the `type="button"` so that a submit doesn't happen

```
<button type="button" onClick={props.handleClick}>Submit</button>
```

Changed the callback of the `setState` which you used for logging

```
this.setState({
  firstNames: [...this.state.firstNames, this.state.inputField],
  inputField: ''
}, () => console.log(this.state.firstNames) );
```

When you did it in your original way, the `console.log` would be trigger before you could be sure that the `setState` call has actually happened.

Another note perhaps could be that using `index` for keys can lead to problems afterwards (be it sorting or removing items), a key should be unique. In this code, it's merely a hint

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!
Now another problem is when I hit enter, the input field is cleared but the value does not get added onto the table. How do we usually deal with problem like that?

Comment: I updated the handle for it, you just add the `onSubmit` on the form (and then you can ofcourse revert the button to the standard `submit` button, and forget about the `onClick` event there

Comment: You're awesome! Thank you so much!